# Cannot create a OneToOne relationship

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, orm, typeorm

I'm using `Typeorm` and I'm trying to create a `OneToOne` relationship between two entities: `Project` and `Resource`.
For doing so I did:

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, OneToMany, OneToOne, JoinColumn, PrimaryColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { Customer } from './customer';

@Entity()
export class Project {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public id!: number;

    @Column({ nullable: false })
    public name!: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    public description!: string;
    
    @PrimaryColumn({ nullable: false })
    public customer_id!: number;

    @OneToOne(() => Customer)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'customer_id' })
    public customer!: Customer;

    @Column({ default: false })
    public deleted: boolean = false;
}
```

then I have `Resource` entity:

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, OneToOne, JoinColumn, PrimaryColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { Project } from './project';

@Entity()
export class Resource {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public id!: number;

    @Column({ nullable: false })
    public name!: string;

    @Column()
    public description: string = "";

    @Column()
    public deleted: boolean = false;

    @PrimaryColumn({ nullable: false })
    public project_id!: number;

    @OneToOne(() => Project)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'project_id' })
    public project!: Project;
}
```

Essentially a `Resource` can be associated to one `Project`, so I've defined the `OneToOne` decorator above the `project` property of `Resource`, and then, I've also defined a column called `project_id`, I need this columns for my `API` design.

Usually Typeorm create the `projectId` column, so I've specified with `name` property: `project_id`, the problem's that I got:

> message: "ER_DUP_FIELDNAME: Duplicate column name 'project_id'",
> code: 'ER_DUP_FIELDNAME',
> errno: 1060,
> sqlMessage: "Duplicate column name 'project_id'",
> sqlState: '42S21',
> index: 0,
> sql: 'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `REL_1c2e17cbbe9905b63f1f870679` ON `resource` (`project_id`, `project_id`)',
> name: 'QueryFailedError',
> query: 'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `REL_1c2e17cbbe9905b63f1f870679` ON `resource` (`project_id`, `project_id`)',
> parameters: []
> }

I was able to fix this using:

```
@JoinColumn({ name: 'project_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
```

but I don't understand why in the first setup this didn't worked 'cause I did exactly the same for `Project` entity, in particular linking the `Customer` table and it works.

Also, I'm not sure that this is correct, these are the constraints created:

[image]

and this is the ER so far:

[image]

Comment: It didn't worked because you have a field named *project_id* (the @PrimaryColumn) and another field named *project* with the *name* option set to *project_id*. So as you can see TypeORM is trying to create two fields with the same name. This is the origin of the error.

Comment: You can remove the field *public project_id!: number;* since TypeORM loads the relation *project!: Project;* automatically (only the id or the entire entity if you want) so it's useless.

Comment: If you really want the relation id then use the [@RelationId](https://typeorm.io/#/decorator-reference/relationid) decorator.

Comment: @CarloCorradini thanks for your reply my italian friend. I actually need the field `project_id`, so seems that I should use `@RelationId` decorator, is that right? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, but remember not to map on the DB since @RelationId is mapped on the server when data is fetched. Relation id is used only for representation. The underlying relation is not added/removed/changed when chaining the value.

Comment: @CarloCorradini if you write an anwer I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It didn't worked because you have a field named project_id (the @PrimaryColumn) and another field named project with the name option set to project_id. So as you can see TypeORM is trying to create two fields with the same name. This is the origin of the error.

You can remove the field public project_id!: number; since TypeORM loads the relation project!: Project; automatically (only the id or the entire entity if you want) so it's useless.

If you really want the relation id then use the [@RelationId](https://typeorm.io/#/decorator-reference/relationid) decorator.

Example below:

```js
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, OneToOne, JoinColumn, PrimaryColumn, RelationId } from 'typeorm';
import { Project } from './project';

@Entity()
export class Resource {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public id!: number;

    @Column({ nullable: false })
    public name!: string;

    @Column()
    public description: string = "";

    @Column()
    public deleted: boolean = false;

    // CHANGES HERE
    @RelationId((resource: Resource) => resource.project)
    public project_id!: number;

    @OneToOne(() => Project)
    @JoinColumn()
    public project!: Project;
}
```

Hope it helps :)